# On launch of Other application on top of the first application.static values get reset

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, static-members, android-lifecycle

I am having an application which launches another application in my case Box app. When i come back to the first app all the static values are getting reset.

I still have enough memory for thr first application to run. Can anyone help me handling this scenario?.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Understand that. But the issue is not only in the static values of the  activity from which i have launched the second app. All the static values and models are getting reset through out the first app.

Comment: static database instance is also getting set to null

Comment: and i dont think storing a database instance in onsavedinstancestate is recommended.